# Attribute not being changed on click

Tags: jquery, attr

This code to change the *param* attribute is not working. Please tell me why?

```
$("#button").on("click",function(){
   if($(this).attr("param") == "Off"){
      $(this).attr("param","Play");
   }
   if($(this).attr("param") == "Play"){
      $(this).attr("param","Off");
   }
});
```

[Example on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Amateur09/k8H5Q/7/)

Comment: FYI param is not a valid attribute for DIV tag, you should use in HTML5 attribute data-param

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code changes it once, then changes it back. You should use an `else` statement. Try:

```
$("#button").on("click",function(){

if($(this).attr("param") == "Off"){
    $(this).attr("param","Play");
} else if($(this).attr("param") == "Play"){
    $(this).attr("param","Off");
}

});
```

Comment: oh, thank you, i dont see it... i accept answer afterr 10 minutes, +1.

Answer (score 0):

the @nullability answer is correct, but I prefer using `switch` instead:

```
$("#button").on("click",function(){
    switch($(this).attr("param")) {
        case "Off":
            $(this).attr("param","Play");
            break;
        case "Play":
            $(this).attr("param","Off");
            break;
    }
});
```

[**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tetri/k8H5Q/9/)

Answer (score 0):

although am little late but as a full guide you can try this

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#but").on("click",function(){

if($(this).attr("param") == "Off"){
$(this).attr("param","Play");
}else if($(this).attr("param") == "Play"){
$(this).attr("param","Off");
}

});
});
</script>
<input type="button" id="but" param="Off" value="go" />
```

issue was "if else" as stated by nullability above. your code was changing it for the first time but then at the next moment it was changing it back.